# Pie layout and bundle layout on same svg using d3.js?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, pie-chart, bundle-layout

I'm trying to create something that's like `D3` hierarchical bundling:

http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111116/bundle.html

[image]

Only instead of the of labelling each node, I'd like an arc at the top - like the pie layout.

http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/GQDUS/

[image]

I've removed the labels, and am playing around with the pie chart - drawing it around the dendrogram  - however I'm not seeing how to use the hierarchical data to generate the pie layout.

Anyone done something similiar to this?

Comment: I have yet to deeply look at d3js, but take a look at [the source (line 102-132)](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111116/bundle.html), and the file [flare-imports.json](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111116/flare-imports.json).  I think using a pie chart somehow to display info, versus just text, is a great idea.  Check out [the sunburst](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/sunburst.html) and [wheel](http://www.jasondavies.com/coffee-wheel/) examples as well.

Comment: Thanks, I've been working on that and unfortunately have to do a bunch of server side processing and then doing multiple graphs to get the effect I want.  I was hoping to just be able to borrow someone else's work.

Comment: It's not clear how to do this by looking at the source?